# A question about regularity results in the Elliptic case which are given by Schauder theory

Tags: elliptic-pde, regularity

I've been reading Jost's lecture notes "Nonlinear Methods in Riemannian and Kählerian Geometry". In section 2.2 he gives a regular results about Elliptic and parabolic equations, but he doesn't prove it. And he says we can find elliptic results in "Gilbarg, D., and N.S. Trudinger, Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order, Springer, Grundlehren 224, Berlin, Heidelberg, New York, 1977" A classic book on elliptic equations.
[the theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqtQa.png)
But I did not find a proof of this theorem in this book. So how should I prove this regularity result? Or does anyone know where this theorem comes from?

Comment: The interior Holder estimates are  Theorem 6.2 in Gilbarg-Trudinger wuth complete proof. I am looking  at the 1983 edition but the authors say that they have not changed chapters 1-8. They have added a new chapter 9.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu I noticed it early， but the domain seems different

Comment: To get the result in Jost  take  the  domain $\Omega$ in  Thm 6.2. Gilbarg-Trudinger to be the ball $B(0,r)$ in Jost Sec..2.2.  You get a Holder estimate on $B(0,r)$  and thus a Holder estimate on the smaller region $B(0,r/2)$.